# createInput() doesn't behave as expected when called from within imported model

Tags: angularjs, p5.js

I'm trying to call createInput() from within an imported class, however, from within the class I lose access to input.style() and the dom element becomes non-responsive(can't click it).

I imagine this is some sort of scope problem as calling createInput() on the same level as my canvas works without issue.

From my canvas component:

```
  s.setup = () => {
      ...
      search = new Search(s.width/2, s.height/3, 500, 1, world, s);
      ...
  }

  s.draw = () => {
      ...
      search.show(s)
      ...
  }
```

And my Search Model:

```
export class Search {
    ...
    show(p5) {
       p5.push();
       search = p5.createInput().addClass('search');
       search.position(pos.x, pos.y);
       search.style('width', this.width + 'px');
       search.style('height', this.height + 'px');
       p5.pop();
    }
}
```

And to clarify,

```
    search = s.createInput().addClass('search');
    search.position(s.width/2-250, s.height/3);
    search.style('width', '500px');
    search.style('height', '40px');
```

works fine called directly from canvas component.

Comment: I'm calling it in draw() and, in doing so, creating a new input field every tick. Causing all the issues you might expect that to cause. However, that doesn't explain why I lose access to .style().

Comment: Do you see any errors in your [JavaScript console](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools)?

Comment: @KevinWorkman no errors. Still not sure why lost access to .style() but I ended up just using JavaScript.